# How to setup Anthos config management properly?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-anthos

I tried to setup Anthos config management and when I try to run

```
gsutil cp gs://config-management-release/released/latest/config-management-operator.yaml config-management-operator.yaml
```

It shows this error

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 usendanayake@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.list access to config-management-release.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. Add necessary storage roles to mentioned user in  https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin.

Comment: I have already added necessary storage roles (Storage Object Admin and Storage Admin both)
But still the same error

Comment: Looks like you should have active Anthos entitlement according to this https://cloud.google.com/anthos-config-management/downloads#troubleshooting. Try contacting sales.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use a whitelisted service account.